# Add normalization layer at the begining of a pre-trained model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a pretrained UNet model with the following architecture

```
UNet(
  (encoder1): Sequential(
    (enc1conv1): Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc1norm1): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc1relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (enc1conv2): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc1norm2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc1relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (pool1): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (encoder2): Sequential(
    (enc2conv1): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc2norm1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc2relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (enc2conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc2norm2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc2relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (pool2): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (encoder3): Sequential(
    (enc3conv1): Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc3norm1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc3relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (enc3conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc3norm2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc3relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (pool3): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (encoder4): Sequential(
    (enc4conv1): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc4norm1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc4relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (enc4conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (enc4norm2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (enc4relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (pool4): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
  (bottleneck): Sequential(
    (bottleneckconv1): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bottlenecknorm1): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (bottleneckrelu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (bottleneckconv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (bottlenecknorm2): BatchNorm2d(512, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (bottleneckrelu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (upconv4): ConvTranspose2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
  (decoder4): Sequential(
    (dec4conv1): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec4norm1): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec4relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (dec4conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec4norm2): BatchNorm2d(256, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec4relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (upconv3): ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
  (decoder3): Sequential(
    (dec3conv1): Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec3norm1): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec3relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (dec3conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec3norm2): BatchNorm2d(128, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec3relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (upconv2): ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
  (decoder2): Sequential(
    (dec2conv1): Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec2norm1): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec2relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (dec2conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec2norm2): BatchNorm2d(64, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec2relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (upconv1): ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(2, 2), stride=(2, 2))
  (decoder1): Sequential(
    (dec1conv1): Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec1norm1): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec1relu1): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (dec1conv2): Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (dec1norm2): BatchNorm2d(32, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (dec1relu2): ReLU(inplace=True)
  )
  (conv): Conv2d(32, 1, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
)
```

The model takes an input which has been normalized using min-max normalization. Instead, I want to add a batch/layer norm layer at the beginning so that I can feed the image as it is without normalization.

I don't want to use torchvision.transforms to normalize the image, instead I want to add a layer at the beginning that does the same work for me.

Comment: What have you tried so far, have you tried wrapping your model in a new `nn.Module`?

Comment: @Ivan I have only tried adding the the layer using nn.Sequential(nn.BatchNorm2d(3), mymodel)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your pretrained model with a `nn.Module` that will use the `UNet` in its forward definition:

```
class UNetWrapper(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, unet):
        super(UNetWrapper, self).__init__()
        self.norm = nn.BatchNorm2d(3)
        self.unet = unet

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.norm(x)
        return self.unet(x)
```

I don't know how you want to proceed from there, either finetune the first layer (might not be that easy...). Or set the `nn.BatchNorm2d` parameters yourself and apply `.eval` on the whole wrapper to lock the batch norm layers and the `UNet` for evaluation.